# ImportError: No module named pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk, enthought, canopy

I am using the latest enthought canopy 1.4.1. It is installed on the stock python 2.7.8 When I try to run an executable file that utilizes pygtk, I receive an import error.

```
dhcp-v034-026:~ austintravis$ oof2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/austintravis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/oof2", line 38, in <module>
oof.run()
File "/Users/austintravis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oof2/ooflib/common/oof.py", line 641, in run
front_end(no_interp)  # all non-parallel menu items are executed here.
File "/Users/austintravis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oof2/ooflib/common/oof.py", line 357, in front_end
import pygtk
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

I was hoping someone could direct me on how to run this application through the system python instead of the enthought one. I feel like I need to specify the full path to the executable but am unsure how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you install pygtk?

Comment: using the version of `pip` that comes with Canopy, just run `pip install pygtk`...

Comment: Yes I installed pygtk using macports. However, it seems to be unable to find the file path.

Comment: When I run `pip install pygtk`, I receive an error message that `Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows.` Which is unhelpful since I am building on a mac.

Comment: "Canopy... is installed on the stock python 2.7.8": No, Canopy is not installed on system python. It is a completely separate python distribution. "I installed pygtk using macports". You can't install into Canopy using Macports. If you want to try installing into Canopy correctly, see https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

Comment: pygtk has other dependencies also, it is very easy install from source but you may need to install python-gtk also. http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2

Answer (score 2):

Check your `sys.path`

It seems that your interpreter is being loaded from a wrong location (`/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin/`)

If that is the case do following:

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python*`

This scenario can happen if you tried to build and install python directly from the source tarball. This can put its binaries to an "Ubuntu-unfriendly" location.

The problem is rooted in the fact that `/usr/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin` in the `PATH` variable.